# Not able to get functions on onClick event of button at runtime in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

### MY HTML page:

in Header region of the page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddEmployee() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var Product = {
            Name: $('#txtTitle').val(),
            Price: $('#txtPrice').val(),
            Category: $('#txtGenre').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:62310/api/products',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(employee),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                WriteResponse(data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

on click of btnAdd button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="AddEmployee()" Text="Add" />
```

---

But when i run the asp.net project it says 
aspx page does not contains defination for "AddEmployee()" function.

Please give your suggestions 
thanks in advance.
Sunil Jadhav

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE : there is a button on page that has onclick event assigned to AddEmployee().

Comment: Where do you use Product ? and why not add the onclick with jQuery? in ASP is is likely not just onclick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClientClick="AddEmployee()" Text="Add" />
```

make it `OnClientClick` instead of `OnClick`

`OnClientClick` is used to hadle the event at client side whereas `OnClick` is used to hadle event on server side.